# What actually happens when I call my module with the same name of a stdlib package?

Tags: go, go-modules

I had a curious situation while learning go a few moments ago. Without knowing that a "sync" package already exists in stdlib, I create a module sync via `go mod init sync` and curiously while trying to run one of my test files within it with `go test` it was obviously not running it (I put inside an always failing test) because it was going for 2 seconds and signaling at the end that all test were passing.

Took me some time (and A LOT of other modifies and researches) to finally try to modify the name of my module to something else before casually solving the problem. I even tried to change the `package sync` on top of my file without success.

So my question is: what is actually happening in the go runtime/tester? Why I don't get at least an error/warning that my module is ""overwriting"" (or whatever is happening)  the stdlib `sync` package? What is really running `go test` and why is it ignoring my own testfiles in the directory?

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but this is exactly why a [module name should begin with a repository](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path)

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the tip, I was following an unofficial tutorial ( https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests ) and in the examples that was not the case. I'll stick to your suggestion from now on

Comment: You can't override packages of the standard lib that way (I know that wasn't your intention). If you name your module and package `sync`, running `go test` will test the `sync` package from the standard lib. Use the `-v` flag to see more info. You get the same output if you run `go test -v sync`. (You might need to add `-count=1` to avoid showing cached test results immediately.)

Comment: related: [Why we should use a URL for the Go module name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724050/why-we-should-use-a-url-for-the-go-module-name) and [Go library package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218423/go-library-package-names)

Comment: "what is actually happening in the go runtime/tester?" The runtime has no stake here and what go test does is not fixed for ever (e.g. Go 1.22 might behave a bit differently) so this doesn't make a good answer because you cannot rely on what Go 1.19.1 does in this case. It's best to stopp worrying about what happens when you do illegal things and just remember to do it properly.